# AWS Elasticsearch snapshot stuck in state IN_PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am using ElasticService from AWS. I am receiving `Snapshot failure status` in Overall health. I can see, there is one snapshot that is stuctk for almost 2 days.

```
id                                                            status start_epoch start_time end_epoch  end_time duration indices successful_shards failed_shards total_shards
2020-07-13t13-30-56.2a009367-21fd-48ab-accc-36a3f61db683 IN_PROGRESS 1594647056  13:30:56   0          00:00:00     1.8d     342                 0             0            0
```

I am not allowed to DELETE this snapshot:
`{"Message":"Your request: '/_snapshot/cs-automated-enc/2020-07-13t13-30-56.2a009367-21fd-48ab-accc-36a3f61db683' is not allowed."}`

I do not know what to do next. I am not able to fix it and lot of API calls does not work as it normally should do. I can see, it suddenly solved by itself after 2 days, but basically I do not know how to fix it and where is/was the problem.

Questions:

1. May I configure where should, and how often should elastic create snapshot of whole cluster? Or maybe just choose which index should be snapshoted?
2. May I see files in `cs-automated-enc` in S3 or is it not available for user, its included in Elastic AWS service?
3. Does snapshots stored in `cs-automated-enc` included in Elasticsearch price?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?